# Why does rbinom give me nas here in R?

Tags: r, na

After some debugging I've narrowed the issue down to the following:

```
  minc <- function(split, population, base, lift = 0.1) {
      control.pop <- population * (1- split)
      test.pop <- population*split

      control.cr <- base
      test.cr <- control.cr*(1+lift)

      #### print statements ####
      print(c(control.pop, control.cr))  # print values of variables
      print( rbinom(1, 5800.0 , 0.1)) # print rbinom for the values
      print( rbinom(1, control.pop, control.cr))  # print rbinom for the variables
    }


    minc(0.8, population = 29000, base = 0.1, lift = 0.1)
```

Which gives the output

```
[1] 5800.0    0.1
[1] 589
[1] NA
```

That is, 
I'm printing the values of the variables passed, and then rbinom for those values - and it works fine - but when I do rbinom for the variables I get NA. What's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rbinom wants an integer for the size you can do

`control.pop <- as.integer(population * (1 - split)`

As @ben-bolker points out using `round` will round to an integer rather than just truncate:

`control.pop <- round(population * (1 - split))`

Comment: or maybe `round(population*(1-split))` (`as.integer()` truncates)

Comment: Agree I'll add `round` to the solution. The problem itself  has something to do with the way R  handles the calculation. So for example this:

`control.pop <- population * .2`
works fine.

but this throws an error

`control.pop <- population * (1 - .8)`

Comment: Thanks!! Don't want to admit how much time I spent on this :P